# SharePoint dataformwebpart get document path without document name and folder url

Tags: xslt, data-form-web-part

I have a dataformwebpart that queries multiple document libraries. I need to open the document properties in a modal window. I have used the below

```
<a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                javascript:customShowModalDialog('
                <xsl:value-of select="@FileDirRef" />
                /Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
                &amp;Source=
                <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentUrl" />
                ', '
                <xsl:value-of select="@FileLeafRef" />
                ', true, true, true)</xsl:attribute>

                <img width="16" height="16" class="ms-MenuUIULImg" src="/_layouts/images/EditItem.gif" alt="" title="" />
            </a>
```

The problem is that @FileDirRef returns the path of the item inside its folder so the generated url is: /sitename/document library/folder name

eg:

('/DocumentCenter/Bonuses Documents/370; CRM5111/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=4') where (370; CRM5111) is the folder name.

In order to be able to open the document properties I must have the above path without the folder name, meaning: /sitename/document library/

eg: ('/DocumentCenter/Bonuses Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=4')

Can anyone point into the right direction to implement this?